# extract values from a variable table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i have a spreadsheet with many information, i want to extract automatically just a few information from some columns, in particular, I want to have a summary where I have 3 out of 10 or more columns (everytime the columns are not in the same position, at the moment they are column B, G and k, but next time might be column B, G, and L):

I know how to get the number of the column i want to extract, how can I tell excel to extract data from each of those? and filter them based on values of one of those column?
is it better a formula or a macro?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. You can probably do this with FILTER. If you add an example we can help you figure it out.

Comment: Hi, thanks, here is the link to download the sample!

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iAlRClG72zgKE1XBtLecYc0EqNNIFIDv/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100078737359954166019&rtpof=true&sd=true) _italic_ **bold** `code`

I want to get the last little table in the second tab!
Thanks for the help

Comment: You can use this tool to copy your table and generate it as markdown table, which you can use in your question: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables.

Without the data no-one's going to help you, but also it would not help somebody in the future having the same problem to recognize this question to be about the same.

Comment: @Sebastiano generally here on SU or any SE site, the right approach is to include screenshots and preferably markdown tables of your problem. Some illustration embedded in the question itself. Many (including myself) will not open links to files.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I was having doubts on what was the best way to share the info. I am going to attach some screenshot as you suggested:


Phase 1: the initial output
https://i.imgur.com/lxxUMQf.png

Phase 2: I transform it into a table
https://i.imgur.com/9iFT2SK.png

Phase 3: I extract only what I need
https://i.imgur.com/gEIFB7F.png

Basically I want to get a summary and in it I want to have only the data from the row when the column  "D" says "extract"

Answer (score 0):

If you are on **`MS365`** you could try using <kbd>FILTER()</kbd>, <kbd>CHOOSECOLS()</kbd> & <kbd>XMATCH()</kbd> Functions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L69</kbd>

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[D]="Extract"),XMATCH(L68:O68,Table1[#Headers]))
```

---

[image]

---

**Notes:**

- Change cell references and ranges accordingly as per your suit.
- <kbd>FILTER()</kbd> Function is used to extract the data from the **`Table1`** with the criteria which includes only **`Extract`**
- You need to have the headers same as shown in the screenshot in the summary output in order to return the required columns for the result data.
- <kbd>XMATCH()</kbd> Function is takes up the headers in summary as **lookup_value** and the headers in the **`Table1`** as **lookup_array** to return the relative positions of the values.
- Using the above, as **`Column Number Reference`** <kbd>CHOOSECOLS()</kbd> returns the columns from the array returned using <kbd>FILTER()</kbd>
- Also, if you are aware of the column number reference and don't want the above solution to be dynamic then you could do the following as well.

---

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[D]="Extract"),1,2,13,17)
```

---

However, if you aren't using **`MS365`** then you could use <kbd>INDEX()</kbd> with <kbd>AGGREGATE()</kbd> function along with <kbd>MATCH()</kbd> Functions which does exactly the same as above method.

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Table1[D])-ROW($O$9)+1)/
  (Table1[D]="Extract"),ROWS(L$68:L68)),MATCH(L$68,Table1[#Headers],0)),"")
```

---